# Unable to read the data from kafka topics using spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka, kafka-topic

I am trying to read the data from the kafka topic using the spark streaming. I am able to produce the message into the kafka topic, but whilereading the data from topic using spark streaming i am getting error message as given below:

```
ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

below is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import pprint

conf= SparkConf().setAppName(“streaming test”).setMaster(“yarn-client”)
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc=StreamingContext(sc,10)

topic = “newone”
broker = {“metadata.broker.list”: “URL”}
direct = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,broker,“test”,{topic:1})

direct.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

*Output Operations on DStreams*

> print() - Prints the first ten elements of every batch of data in a
>   DStream on the driver node running the streaming application. This is
>   useful for development and debugging. Python API This is called 
>   `pprint`() in the Python API.

`java.util.Hashmap` is coming in the message i.e. `InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[K, V]]`   you want to print that, while and hence `java.lang.ClassCastException`

you have to parse the message and print it like [this](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/)...

```
 direct.transform(...).map(lambda ...)
```

examples here :[tests.py](https://github.com/alec-heif/MIT-Thesis/blob/master/spark-bin/python/pyspark/streaming/tests.py)